# How to write a program that opens file neovim in Powershell after clicking on it

Tags: powershell, neovim

(Windows) I've been working on a batch file that opens neovim in Powershell 7 when it is run. At the moment, the code is simple--all it does is open the neovim filetree in powershell:

```
@echo off
call pwsh.exe -NoExit -Command "& {nvim.exe .}"
```

However, eventually, I want to change it to something like the following:

```
@echo off
call pwsh.exe -NoExit -Command "& {nvim.exe filename}"
```

And make it so that when I click on a file named "filename," and I click "Open With," I can reference this batch file which will open it in neovim in the Powershell.

How could I go about writing a program like this? I'm not sure what to substitute in place of "filename," and I don't know how I would be able to connect this batch script to the "Open With" program.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need that batch file. If you want to call powershell, a powershell script is better choice ;)
2. **Open with ...** context menu depends on file type. The corresponding editor is stored in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<FILE TYPE>\Shell\Edit\Command`. The value could be like this:

```
     pwsh.exe -NoExit -Command "nvim.exe "%1""
```

*(you must test it, I didn't try... if it doesn't work, full path could help...)*